# Guessing game code in C Programming

Tags: c

Hello i am new to C programming, currently working on a code, a simple guessing game. Maybe not simple for me, Every time i build and run the code.  At the first attempt. The command interface asks to press any key to continue and then takes the interface away. I have to start from the beginning and it doesn't let me go any further unless i run the code again as it is meant to allow another guessed number  until the game is over or until i guess right. i do not know what is wrong with my code. Please help, Code is attached below. Thank you.

```
while(match ==0 && chance_count <= MAX_CHANCES){

    printf("Enter your number: ");
        scanf("%match", &user_guess);
        if(user_guess > computer_guess)
        {
            printf("your guess is high\n");
            printf("your remaining chances are %d\n", MAX_CHANCES - chance_count);
            printf("number of steps taken is %d\n", chance_count);

    }
       else if (user_guess <  computer_guess){
                 printf("your guess is too low\n");
                 printf("your remaining chances are %d\n",MAX_CHANCES - chance_count);
                 printf("number of steps taken is %d\n", chance_count);

    }
       else{
                 printf("BINGO! you have won\n");
                 printf("it took you %d steps for the number\n", MAX_CHANCES - (MAX_CHANCES - chance_count));

    }
    break;
                 printf("\n\n");
                 chance_count++;
    } // end of while loop
     if(chance_count > MAX_CHANCES){
                 printf("GAME OVER");
    }
          return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `scanf("%match", &user_guess);` does? `%match` is not a valid format spec. You don't show the variable type with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but my **user guess** is `int` and if so it should be `scanf("%d", &user_guess);` and of course you need to check the return value from `scanf` too to see if the input was converted successfully.

Comment: Your `break` is executed unconditionally. Move it up one line so it's inside the last `else` block.

Comment: Instead of using a `break`, you should set `match` to 1, which will make the `while` condition fail and stop your program.

Comment: Hey guys! thanks every changes to pointed errors yielded positive result. it worked! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%match", &user_guess);
```

Wrong. There's no such placeholders in `scanf` format string. Read this carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

Your `break;` matches with `while(match ==0 && chance_count <= MAX_CHANCES)`

So, it will run only first time once the condition is true.

Comment: @Pablo  Thanks for your adjustment.

Comment: "Wrong" is a blame, but how do you fix it? This is what OP wants to know.

Comment: @Ring See the code right there above! There's no any complicated algorithms there. And why is "wrong" a blame? 'Wrong' is just 'Wrong' because he is wrong. That's not a kind of humiliation. Have you ever seen "%match" in scanf? Have ever seen such a break statement which makes only one time execution in loop without any plausible conditional statements? I thought only slight adjustment in his code is quite enough to make him do whatever he wants.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of your approach you can use a infinite loop `while(1);` and break out of it if some criteria are meet. In this way your code will be more readable, efficient and scalable.

So there is no need to use a flag variable 'match', in the else statement add a `break();` command at the end if the user guess the right number.

Also use an if statement to check if the user has more chances to guess, or he has suppressed them.

Last but not least you have to replace `scanf("%match", &user_guess);` with `scanf("%d", &user_guess);` because you need to read an int variable from the user and store it at the 'user_guess' variable

```
 while(1)
 {
        printf("Enter your number: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_guess);

        if(user_guess > computer_guess)
        {
          printf("your guess is high\n");
          printf("your remaining chances are %d\n", MAX_CHANCES - chance_count);
          printf("number of steps taken is %d\n", chance_count);
        }
        else if (user_guess <  computer_guess)
        {
           printf("your guess is too low\n");
           printf("your remaining chances are %d\n",MAX_CHANCES - chance_count);
           printf("number of steps taken is %d\n", chance_count);
        }
        else
        {
         printf("BINGO! you have won\n");
         printf("it took you %d steps for the number\n", chance_count);
         break;
        }

        if(chance_count > MAX_CHANCES)
        {
          printf("GAME OVER");
          break;
        }

        chance_count++;
 } // end of while loop
```

Comment: Please make your answer better by explaining your correction so that the OP and other people in the feature can learn from this.

Comment: You should not encourage the use of `break` in loop. Instead use a better stop condition.

Comment: I added some documentation to explain my code for further purposes. Thanks for pointing out @Pablo

Comment: Hey guys! thanks every changes to pointed errors yielded positive result. it worked! Thanks! :D